# The output screen stays for a second?

Tags: c++

When I run the following program the console window only stays open for a second if I only have one call to `getchar()` before I exit main.  If I add a second call to `getchar()` then it keeps the console window open.  What is the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void selectionSort(int [], const int, bool (*)( int, int ));
bool ascending ( int, int );
bool descending ( int, int );
void swap(int * const, int * const);

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 10;
    int a[ arraySize ] = { 1, 22, 2 ,44 ,3 , 4, 6, 0, 7, 5 };
    int order;
    cout << "Enter 1 to sort in ascending order and 2 for descending " << endl;
    cin >> order;
    if ( order == 1 )
        selectionSort( a, arraySize, ascending );
    if ( order ==2 )
        selectionSort( a, arraySize, descending );
    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
        cout << a[i] << " ";        

    cout << endl;
    getchar();
              //getchar(); only if i use this version of getchar output screen remains
    return 0;
}

bool ascending ( int x, int y )
{
    return x < y;
}

bool descending ( int x, int y )
{
    return x > y;
}

void swap(int * const x, int * const y)
{
int temp = *x;
*x = *y;
 *y = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int work[], const int size, bool (*compare)( int, int ))
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++ )
    {
    int smallestOrLargest = i;
        for ( int index = i + 1; index < size; index++ )
        {
            if ( !(*compare)( work[ smallestOrLargest ], work[ index ] ) )
                swap( &work[ smallestOrLargest ], &work[ index ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there is still input in the input stream.  the first call to `getchar()` will see this input, grab it and then return.  When you add the second `getchar()` there is no more input so it blocks until you press enter.  If you want to make sure there is nothing left in the input buffer than you can use:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This consumes up to `streamsize::max` characters from the stream until it reaches a newline and then consumes the newline as long as it didn't read `streamsize::max` characters.  this should leave an empty buffer for `getchar()`.